# Different Section Header Style in ChildView

Tags: swiftui

I use a `Form` which gives me the following `Section`-Header-Style:

[image: with form]

As a ChildView, I want to display a list with different sections. However, the section header is wrong/broken and is not sticky as it is supposed to be. It should look like this:

[image]

If I change the the `Form` to a `List` both header styles become sticky.

How can I have `Form`-Headers in the ParentView but `List` (sticky) headers in the ChildView?

Here is some sample code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            // change to List for different Section Header Style
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Section Style 1")){
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()){ Text("Go to Child") }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Section Style")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView:View{
    var items:[Item] = []
    init(){
        self.items = [Item(id:1), Item(id:2), Item(id:3), Item(id:4), Item(id:5), Item(id:6), Item(id:7), Item(id:8)]
    }
    var body: some View{
        List{
            Section(header:Text("Sticky Header Style")){
                ForEach(self.items, id:\.id){item in
                    Text(String(item.id))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Item {
    var id: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PlainListStyle` as below

```
struct ChildView:View{
    var items:[Item] = []
    init(){
        self.items = [Item(id:1), Item(id:2), Item(id:3), Item(id:4), Item(id:5), Item(id:6), Item(id:7), Item(id:8)]
    }
    var body: some View{
        List{
            Section(header:Text("Sticky Header Style")){
                ForEach(self.items, id:\.id){item in
                    Text(String(item.id))
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(PlainListStyle()) // << here is a fix !
    }
}
```